# How to set up broadband connection in Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop version

Tags: networking, broadband

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows Xp. My broadband connection working ok in Windows Xp, but it is not working in Ubuntu. I want to connect through LAN over PPPoE.

Please guide me on how to set up a wired DSL connection.

Comment: Please expand on what you are willing to do, and what you've tried so far.. how is your network router setup?

Answer (score 2):

Open network connections by searching for it in the dash.

Now Click on the **Add** button.

[image]

Choose the network type as **DSL** and then click **create**.

[image]
[image]

Now type the username and password and save.

[image]

You can also choose to connect automatically in the **general** tab.

Answer (score 0):

I ran one command at terminal sudo pppoeconf and internet connection was established. The network applet shows device not managed, but my internet connection works fine.

So, my problem is resolved.