# Unable to connect to wired connection using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, lan

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my LAN Internet is not working. My wifi is working properly but I can access LAN Internet.

First it keep connecting but later it says you are now offline. On my windows 8 it is working fine.

Can anybody please help.

Here are the results of `ifconfig eth0`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:89:84:40:63:01  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16
```

Here are the sittings of my window 8 and how they look like:

Ethernet: [Ethernet Tab](http://postimg.org/image/m7fdkwknt/)

Broadband: [Broadband Tab](http://postimg.org/image/qf858ebnl/)

More Link you can find in the @Rishabh answer.

Comment: try from the terminal:  `ifconfig eth0`, and provide the result

Comment: I have added Sir. Please review.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more about your network. As in, you have a DHCP service which issues IP or you're configuring IP's manually. Further, please post the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` :)

Comment: yes I am configuring manually as I need to provide user name and password for authentication to connect to LAN.

Comment: The command you provided says: no such file or directory.

Comment: Try again > `cat /etc/network/interfaces`
Further, what you meant by authentication?? Could you explain that as well?

Comment: @user3228030 how did you do that? i.e. setup LAN with username and password?

Comment: @AzkerM I mean I create DSL connection from EDIT Connection and in the DSL tab I put my username and password. Because my provider setup some username password in order to get connected with internet connection. I have put this info as well.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Yes Sir. I create new connection using Edit Connection tab and there I press Add and then Selects DSL first from drop-down and then put my information in the DSL tab like my username and password because without this info I cant get linked with provider internet.

Comment: So, its basically a PPPoE, thus the connectivity is through a LAN medium. Could you use delete those profiles under **DSL** tab and then try the command line method. Open up a terminal & type `sudo pppoeconf` , then follow the steps. If you're lost or you wanna look back, refer official ubuntu [**ADSLPPPoE**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE).

Comment: that is DSL, that is not LAN.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Dear Sir, Basically they have provided me the LAN cable only to get connected with the internet so I said this. Sorry for misunderstanding. So, any fix? thank you for you great help so far.

Comment: @AzkerM So, doing this can fix my internet?

Comment: @AzkerM you are right in saying this. It is this sort of internet. :)

Comment: @AzkerM thank you much for your great help so far.

Comment: Doing the terminal way worked for you?? If so, please comment. Either, let me find a dupe or a I'll post it an answer for you to accept.

Comment: No it didn't worked for me. Please find a dupe and post your answer so I will try again. Thank you please.

Comment: @user3228030 could you answer two question: 1) provide output for `ifconfig|grep "Link encap:"`; 2) have you an embedded device for DSL modem?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Sir, output is:
`eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:89:84:40:63:01  
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:94:23:fc:b2:67 `

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ 2nd answer: Yes I do have embedded device for DSL Modem.

Comment: @AzkerM I have used your commands it says 2 test unsuccessful. Not connected. this type of error. any trick?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Added screenshots of windows 8. I have these sittings without any manual entries. I only creates broadband connection myself to enter username password.

Comment: @AzkerM the response of `sudo pppoeconf` command is:
`Sorry, I scanned 2 interfaces, but the Access            │          
          │ Concentrator of your provider did not respond. Please    │          
          │ check your network and modem cables. Another reason for  │          
          │ the scan failure may also be another running pppoe       │          
          │ process which controls the modem.`

Comment: These comments are getting quite messy, can you [edit] your question to include any essential information they might contain so we can clean them up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach the screenshots for ifconfig command (in ubuntu), can you also attach a screenshot of your windows 8 LAN details?

just go to **Network and sharing centre > Local area Connection > Details**

Your network connection is not getting connected automatically because it is a broadband connection. You need to manually set it up

Take a look at -
[How to set up broadband connection in Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488909/how-to-set-up-broadband-connection-in-ubuntu-14-04-desktop-version)
, it might be a possible duplicate to your question and respond if that method works

Comment: I have added Sir in my question.

Comment: your eth0 looks fine (but unconnected), most probably there is a configuration issue, can you put the screenshot of windows 8 lan details

Comment: Ethernet Image: [link](http://postimg.org/image/m7fdkwknt/)

Comment: Broadband Image: [link](http://postimg.org/image/qf858ebnl/)

Comment: More Screen: [link](http://postimg.org/image/sev6j6ojj/)

Comment: More Screen: [link](http://postimg.org/image/eou5x84iz/)

Comment: More Screen: [link](http://postimg.org/image/ga9fp1eqz/)

Comment: check the edit i just made, it should help you out